# jqPlot pie chart - how can I capture a click on a legend item?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Here's the story so far.

1. I've made the pie chart slices clickable so users can click to go to a different page listing the items relevant to that slice.
2. For very small slices it's hard for the user to click them. I would therefore like to have the same functionality for the legend next to the pie chart - click a legend item, go to a URL.
3. There doesn't seem to be any way to hook into a click on the legend. I'm looking for something like jqplotLegendClick. I can use an HTML A element as the legend text, which would be an acceptable solution, BUT when I click it nothing happens!

Any idea how to handle this? I would have thought it's quite a common scenario.

Here's a minimal jsfiddle showing the solution suggested below not working, in case anyone spots an issue. http://jsfiddle.net/Ep4sP/ Here's the js part.

```
$(function ()
{

    var data = [['2012-09-13', 1], ['2012-10-22', 2], ['2012-01-12', 3]];

    $.jqplot('ChartDIV', [data],
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer
        },
        legend: { show: true }
    });

    $('.jqplot-table-legend-label').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            alert('you have clicked on the serie : ' + $(this).html());
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following code AFTER the chart init: http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/272/

```
$('.jqplot-table-legend-label').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert('you have clicked on the serie : ' + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

Note that on recent versions the class name is `.jqplot-table-legend` (tested with 1.0.8)

Comment: Thanks sdespont, especially for taking the time to set the jsfiddle up. Unfortunately I had already tried this and the click event doesn't fire. I assume propagation is being stopped somewhere. I tried incorporating your postDrawHooks code as that seemed relevant but it hasn't helped. I can handle a click on .jqplot-event-canvas which gives me the click coordinates, but not a click on the label itself.

Comment: In fact, it is just an old fiddle about another subject. I have just adapted for the example. Here is a new "essential" version : http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/273/

Comment: As you can see, it is working (click on the legend text to show the alert popup). So what are you doing so different comparing to this fiddle? BTW, I have just "inspect element" (right click on element on Chrome) of the legend to discover that the text have the "jqplot-table-legend-label" class. You could try to check that this class is well applied to your legend text.

Comment: I suppose the most obvious difference between your example and mine (see edit above) is that mine is a pie chart.

Comment: In fact, it is because of legend is drought inside the graph! The legend text are covered by an overlay and cannot catch the click event. If you want this functionality, you need to move your legend outside like this : http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/277/

Comment: I think that's finally what I was looking for! Thanks a lot.

Comment: On version 1.0.8 this is now `.jqplot-table-legend´, so I am editing the answer to reflect both. Please amend the answer so that it can reflect which version it changed at :)